# asyncio stream vs synchronous stream in socket communication with a react native app

Tags: react-native, stream, python-asyncio, micropython

Objective is esp32 running micropython acts as a server while android app acts as a client. Before asyncio stream I am able to communicate successfully, but after switching to asyncio i fail to do so, only android app to esp32 is successful but app is failing to retrieve json output from server and I even tried text strings too . App side code remains unchanged for both synchronous/asyncio codes.

**Desired output:**

```
response = {
'error': 'invalid request',
'status': 'retry'
}
```

**synchronous side:**

```
conn.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n')
conn.send('Content-Type: application/json\n')
conn.send('Connection: close\n\n')
conn.sendall(ujson.dumps(response ))
```

**asyncio side:**

```
swriter.write(ujson.dumps(response ))
await swriter.drain()
```

**react native side:**

```
fetch( 'http://192.168.0.110' )
.then(response => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
const data1 = responseJson;
console.log('getting data from fetch', data1)

setData({ data1 });

onConnectionMessage(data1);


})
```

synchronous way I was able to retrieve the json output sent from esp32 to android app(react native), but the same code using asyncio failed. What am I doing wrong?

**sample asyncio server side code is:**

```
import usocket as socket
import uasyncio as asyncio
import uselect as select
import ujson
from heartbeat import heartbeat  # Optional LED flash

class Server:

    def __init__(self, host='0.0.0.0', port=80, backlog=5, timeout=10):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.backlog = backlog
        self.timeout = timeout

    async def run(self):
        print('Awaiting client connection.')
        self.cid = 0
        asyncio.create_task(heartbeat(100))
        self.server = await asyncio.start_server(self.run_client, self.host, self.port, self.backlog)
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(100)

    async def run_client(self, sreader, swriter):
        self.cid += 1
        print('Got connection from client', self.cid)
        try:
            while True:
                try:
                    res = await asyncio.wait_for(sreader.readline(), self.timeout)
                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    res = b''
                if res == b'':
                    raise OSError
                print('Received {} from client {}'.format(ujson.loads(res.rstrip()), self.cid))
                response = {
                'error': 'invalid request',
                'status': 'retry'
                 }
                swriter.write(ujson.dumps(response))
                await swriter.drain()  # Echo back
        except OSError:
            pass
        print('Client {} disconnect.'.format(self.cid))
        await sreader.wait_closed()
        print('Client {} socket closed.'.format(self.cid))

    async def close(self):
        print('Closing server')
        self.server.close()
        await self.server.wait_closed()
        print('Server closed.')

server = Server()
try:
    asyncio.run(server.run())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Interrupted')  # This mechanism doesn't work on Unix build.
finally:
    asyncio.run(server.close())
    _ = asyncio.new_event_loop()
```

Comment: How do you run the code with asyncio?

Comment: I added the sample server side asyncio code

Comment: Please explain what 'failed' means.

Comment: client doesn't retrieve any response from server just returns empty response after socket is closed, maybe due to readline method which awaits till whole request is fetched due to lower memory allocation

Answer (score -1):

got the error: `asyncio.wait_for(sreader.readline(), self.timeout)`------> changed to

`asyncio.wait_for(sreader.read(2048), self.timeout)`. Now client is recieving json output immediately after closing the socket