# Difference between asyncio stream and synchronous stream for json output to a client

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, micropython, python-sockets

```
response = {
'error': 'invalid request',
'status': 'retry'
}
```

**synchronous side:**

```
conn.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n')
conn.send('Content-Type: application/json\n')
conn.send('Connection: close\n\n')
conn.sendall(ujson.dumps(response ))
```

**asyncio side:**

```
swriter.write(ujson.dumps(response ))
await swriter.drain()
```

**Client was to able to read json response in synchronous way but reading failed in asyncio, Where is the error?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asyncio stream vs synchronous stream in socket communication with a react native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69163368/asyncio-stream-vs-synchronous-stream-in-socket-communication-with-a-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

got the error: `asyncio.wait_for(sreader.readline(), self.timeout)`------> changed to

`asyncio.wait_for(sreader.read(2048), self.timeout)`. Now client is recieving json output immediately after closing the socket. Just a timing issue